# ¿Qué os parece si unimos las etiquetas <tiempos-verbales↔verb-moods> y <formas-de-verbos↔tiempos-verbales>?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Sugiero la unión de las siguientes etiquetas:

- [tiempos-verbales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiempos-verbales) → [verb-moods](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-moods)
- [formas-de-verbos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formas-de-verbos) → [tiempos-verbales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiempos-verbales)

Soy consciente de que el método a usar es sugerirlas como sinónimas para que luego aparezcan en [Suggested tag synonyms](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) y que la gente lo vote.

Sin embargo, viendo la nula atención que reciben las propuestas allí y que se necesita un mínimo de votos para proceder, creo que es mejor que un moderador se encargue si la comunidad le da el visto bueno.

Comment: Sí estoy de acuerdo, veamos qué dicen los otros moderadores. Sin embargo los tags nombres y sustantivos no son necesariamente lo mismo. Por la tercera opción de unión no estoy de acuerdo...

Comment: @Joze también yo dudé. No me queda demasiado claro qué se quiere usar en cada una de esas etiquetas.

Comment: Sí... las descripciones son intercambiables. Hay que encontrar una buena descripción para cada una que no deje lugar a dudas...

Comment: @Joze hagamos una cosa: elimino este ítem de la lista y creo una pregunta por separado en la que abordar este deslinde.

Comment: Para votar en "Suggested tag synonyms" se necesita mucha reputación y tal vez por eso no hay casi contribuciones. Yo con mis pobres 1800 no puedo contribuir.  :(

Comment: @DGaleano en verdad el sistema de votar por los sinónimos de etiquetas es bastante poco práctico: necesita muchos votos y de gente que tenga una cierta reputación en esa etiqueta. Por ello, las sugerencias se enquistan y nunca se resuelven. Si algún día tienes alguna sugerencia de fusión de etiquetas es mejor añadirla como pregunta aqui en Meta, para que algún administrador lo haga manualmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al estar de acuerdo Joze y no haber opiniones en contra, he procedido a mapear

[verb-moods](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-moods) y [formas-de-verbos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formas-de-verbos) → [tiempos-verbales](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiempos-verbales)